# Magento 2 Installation, 404 Files

Tags: magento, magento2

After the installation of Magento 2 I get some errors. I share the screenshot of the error below. The error is exactly. 
Error: Magento is first installed with version folder. Example: pub/static/versionxxxxxxx/ 
A sample url address;

```html
https://furnitica.com/pub/static/version1547110740/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js
```

But if we make changes to this url ( I will delete version folder url )

```html
https://furnitica.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css
```

This works smoothly. Worked when I moved the files to the version folder. But this is not a valid solution because the name of the version folder changes continuously.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento shows 404 for static content if system is in production mode and static content is not deployed. Deploy static content to resolve it:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```